# Mask function returning empty dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code and am re-learning python. I am trying to apply a mask to extract all flights in the month of may.

However, after I print after applying the mask I receive an empty data frame. Is there something I'm missing, this is a csv file FYI.

Table included.

```
def filter_dataset(flight_data):
  '''
  processing dataset for may flights
  '''
  filtered_set = flight_data[['MONTH', 'ORIGIN', 'ORIGIN_CITY_NAME',
                               'ORIGIN_STATE_NM', 'DEST', 'DEST_CITY_NAME',
                                'DEST_STATE_NM', 'CANCELLED', 'CANCELLATION_CODE', 'DIVERTED']]
  month_mask = filtered_set['MONTH'] == 5
  new_set = filtered_set[month_mask]
  print(new_set)


    YEAR  MONTH  DAY_OF_MONTH  DAY_OF_WEEK                FL_DATE  ... DEST_STATE_ABR  DEST_STATE_NM  CANCELLED  CANCELLATION_CODE DIVERTED
563732  2022      1            25            2  1/25/2022 12:00:00 AM  ...             GA        Georgia        0.0                NaN      0.0
563733  2022      1            26            3  1/26/2022 12:00:00 AM  ...             GA        Georgia        0.0                NaN      0.0
563734  2022      1            27            4  1/27/2022 12:00:00 AM  ...             GA        Georgia        0.0                NaN      0.0
563735  2022      1            28            5  1/28/2022 12:00:00 AM  ...             GA        Georgia        0.0                NaN      0.0
563736  2022      1            29            6  1/29/2022 12:00:00 AM  ...             GA        Georgia        0.0                NaN      0.0
```

Comment: In the example dataset you provide, there are only items with `"MONTH" == 1`. Are you sure there are some rows with `"MONTH" == 5` in the table? Two good checks are: `print(filtered_set['MONTH'].dtype)` to make sure the type is integer (like you are expecting in your comparison) and `print(filtered_set['MONTH'].unique())` to show all the unique months in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be correct. Maybe you have a dtype issue.
For example, you can't compare str with int.

Solution: Check [dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) of df columns

```
df.dtypes
```

Example: Month: str and Month: int

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': list(range(12)) * 2, 'randint': np.random.randint(0, 29, size=24)})
df.month = df.month.astype(str)
dfmask = df.month == 2
print(df[dfmask])
df.month = df.month.astype(int)
dfmask = df.month == 2
print(df[dfmask])
```